# How to load compressed kernel modules in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, compression

I would like to use LZMA-compressed kernel modules on my system. Unfortunately Canoncial leaves that feature disabled both in kernel and user-space tools. Here's what I did so far:

1. Compile and install the current [14.04.05-LTS kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git/log/?h=lts-backport-xenial) (v4.4.19) with:

   ```
   CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS=y
   CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ=y
   ```

   After installation I can now see a bunch of `.ko.xz` files in `/lib/modules/4.4.19-37.56+/kernel/`.
2. Backport the `kmod_22` package from Xenial (16.04) to Trusty (14.04) configured with the `--with-xz` option. This seems to work too.
3. Run `update-initrams -u -k 4.4.19-37.56+`.

What works so far:

- arbitrary operations on uncompressed modules (like those built by DKMS):

  ```
  $ modinfo nvidia_370
  filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.19-37.56+/updates/dkms/nvidia_370.ko
  […]
  ```
- showing compressed modules by their full path:

  ```
  modinfo /lib/modules/4.4.19-37.56+/kernel/fs/jfs/jfs.ko.xz
  ```
- loading compressed modules without (missing) dependencies by their full path:

  ```
  insmod /lib/modules/4.4.19-37.56+/kernel/fs/jfs/jfs.ko.xz
  ```
- unloading such modules:

  ```
  rmmod jfs
  ```

What doesn't work:

- Unloading with `modprobe -r`.
- Any other operation with just a package name but no path, e. g.:

  ```
  # insmod jfs
  insmod: ERROR: could not load module jfs: No such file or directory
  # modprobe jfs
  modprobe: FATAL: Module jfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.19-37.56+
  ```

So, for modules without dependencies like `jfs` there's a work-around where I can just specify the full module file path to `insmod`, but this is both annoying and doesn't perform dependency resolution like `modprobe`.

I suppose that the kernel module directory somehow doesn't pick up compressed module files. **How can I load compressed kernel modules by their name with `modprobe`?**

Comment: Did you run `depmod` afterwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `depmod`.

`depmod` (by default) reads the modules under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`, finds which symbols they export and also what they need themselves, then using these info creates the symbol (module) dependencies between modules, and saves it in the file `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep` and also creates a binary hash `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep.bin`.

It also creates two other files:

- `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.symbols` (and it's binary hash `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep.bin`): contains the symbols each module exports
- `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.devname`: contains the `/dev` entry that needs to be created for necessary modules, contains the module name, name of the `/dev` entry and the major, minor numbers

Just to note, you can also run `depmod` for a specific kernel version or on a specific module, check `man depmod`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up running `depmod 4.4.19-37.56+`.

Answer (score 1):

You **need** a **depmod** with **lzma** support to map and allow *loading .xz compreesed kernel modules*

**Some** depmod ship **without** it, so you  may require a binary made by custom build flags, like *--with-xz*

Comment: Of course. However, that was not the issue: `depmod` is part of the `kmod` package which I had already patched to enable xz/LZMA support when I wrote the question (as you can see).

Comment: Sorry, for it was TLDR; and I believed you had failed on that